# Looking to enable and disable (toggle) ADB or USB debugging using command line or in app

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to enable ADB (USB debugging) only when my application is running and disabling it when my application is not. I have full access to the phone and it is rooted, `su` available, etc., but I cannot find a way to do the toggling.

What I've tried so far:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String [] { "su", "-c", "setprop", "persist.service.adb.enable", "0"});
proc.waitFor();
Process proc2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String [] { "su", "-c", "stop", "adbd"});
proc2.waitFor();
```

This however causes the phone to enter a reboot loop instantaneously.

Comment: Question is why are you doing it that way, when the Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging is available?

Comment: Do not think you can achieve that, because of what I have said about the Settings option to enable usb debugging... just saying, its a ROM functionality, someone can easily switch it on... your app should not have to be overriding the entire aspect of it. :)

Comment: My app needs adb to be on to work correctly, and I just want to avoid having adb on 24x7 because of security risks. It's fine if the user (I am the only user, and using a rooted and unlocked and su'd phone) wants to manually toggle it on at other times when my app is not working.

Comment: The ability of someone to grab/do anything on my phone using adb, bypassing the lockscreen, etc..

Comment: The purpose of the app and what I'm trying to do with is just turn adb on when my app needs it, then turn it off when it's done. If another app or a manual toggle turns it back on, no problem at all.

Comment: check http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: Try asking on http://www.xda-developers.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code that works is easy:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 0); // 0 to disable, 1 to enable
```

**Edit/Update:
Thanks to @MohanT for the following update:**

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0); // 0 to disable, 1 to enable
```

However, the app needs to be a system app to be able to use this. To get out of having to sign it, build a custom rom, etc.. I did the following to get it to be a system app.

First, I installed it regularly using eclipse, then adb shell:

```
> su
# mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
# cat /data/app/filename.apk > /system/app/filename.apk
# mount -o remount,ro -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
# reboot
```

Comment: Also add: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve by following next steps:

1. Check whether ADB is currently enabled. To do that you can use a relevant global constant:

   - [`Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html#ADB_ENABLED) for API 17 and above.
   - [`Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ADB_ENABLED) prior to API 17.
2. Use implicit [`Intent`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with [`Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS) action to open developers options, where user can enable or disable ADB.

Code example:

**Java**

```
public static final int API = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
public static final int ENABLED=1, DISABLED=0;

public static boolean adbEnabled(Context context){
    if(API>16)
       return ENABLED == Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED,DISABLED);
    else 
       return ENABLED == Settings.Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED,DISABLED);
}

public void checkAdb(Context context){
    //if ADB disabled
    if(!adbEnabled(context)){
        //open developer options settings 
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Kotlin**

```
val API = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
val ENABLED = 1
val DISABLED = 0

fun adbEnabled(context: Context): Boolean {
    return if (API > 16)
        ENABLED == Settings.Global.getInt(context.contentResolver, Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, DISABLED)
    else
        ENABLED == Settings.Secure.getInt(context.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, DISABLED)
}
fun checkAdb(context: Context) {
    //if ADB disabled
    if (!adbEnabled(context)) {
        //open developer options settings
        val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

> **Just for reference:**
>
> Prior to API 3 (probably no longer relevant) [`Settings.System.ADB_ENABLED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#ADB_ENABLED) was used.

Answer (score 3):

Chris's answer is correct except the ADB_ENABLED field in Secure class has been depreciated and the string has been moved to Global class. So you can use below command -

```
Settings.Global.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0); // 0 to disable, 1 to enable
```

Answer (score 2):

From my experiences using setprop doesn't always work reliable, and might even conflict with the Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging option. Besides that it might be irritating for instance if USB debugging is enabled but adb doesn't work etc. Therefore using Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED is the prefered way... plus you always have the notification in the status panel.

If you don't want to go through the hassle to install your app on system partition when only trying to access Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED then you can instead rely on another app that is doing this work already:

This app is called ADB Toggle. You can find it in Google Play:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ramdroid.adbtoggle

The library to access USB debug settings via ADB Toggle is available here:

https://github.com/ramdroid/AdbToggleAccessLib